# Locate and edit the main HTML file in magento store

Tags: html, magento, locate

I need to add a shadow effect png picture to the top banner in my Magento website tamween.biz, I could do this on my local server using firebug by adding a new class in the right coding area and I have made all selector properties in the bootstrap.css file.

This test was very successful, The problem is I don't know where to locate the real HTML file in the server to edit these changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. HTML code that calls image is in `root/app/design/frontend/<package>/<theme>/template/page/html/header.phtml`
2. Image's path is stored in `System => Configuration => General => Design => Header => Logo Image Src`
3. Any skin is located in `root/skin/frontend/<package>/<theme>/css`

Comment: I've checked these folders and all files inside them, but I can't find the lines I tested online. the source code consist of thousands of lines where these files have only dozen of codes. is it because my website programed with PHP?

Comment: yes. Check the file in par.1 upper and search in it `logo`. Before anything to apply in real site, make a backup

Answer (score 0):

If you have created your custom theme then go to

> root/app/design/frontend//yourtheme/template/page/html/header.phtml

if not then go to

> root/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/html/header.phtml

and the n search for

```
 <img src="<?php echo $this->getLogoSrc() ?>">
```

this is the code that output the image.you can add css class to it.

Comment: `<img src="<?php echo $this->getLogoSrc() ?>` looks malformed. Did you mean to write `<img src="<?php echo $this->getLogoSrc() ?>">` or `<?php echo '<img src="' . $this->getLogoSrc() . '">' ?>`?

Answer (score 0):

Magento HTML page is made up of blocks, and each block has a template file. 
To find out where each block template file is you can add some code to the core and get rid of it after you are done.

Open `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php:241`. This should be in the method `fetchView` and then edit the line having the `include` code to the following

```
        if (strpos($includeFilePath, realpath($this->_viewDir)) === 0 || $this->_getAllowSymlinks()) {
          echo "<!-- template hint start\n";
          echo $includeFilePath."\n";
          echo get_class($this)."\n";
          echo "-->";
            include $includeFilePath;
          echo "<!-- template hint end\n";
          echo $includeFilePath."\n";
          echo get_class($this)."\n";
          echo "-->";
        } else {
```

This will add HTML comments telling you about the template file path and what `$this` means in that context.

([Reference](http://javidh.ir/?p=21))

Answer (score 0):

In magento go to System - > configuration and set template hints yes.

This way you will see each template section from where static blocks will come from.